# Append bash timer to file

Tags: bash, date, echo

I am struggling to both provide a decent timer to a user and append the value in the log. I'm not sure why the following loop isn't logging using exec.

My ideal situation is to add >> log.txt to the echo line, but that breaks the visual timer to the user. 
One workaround is to write a redundant echo line after the first:

Some progress was made

```
  exec > >(tee log.txt) 2>&1
  SECONDS=0
  date1=`date +%s`
  while ! [ $((`date +%s` - $date1)) -gt 10 ]; do
    echo -ne "$(date -u --date @$((`date +%s` - $date1)) +%H:%M:%S)\r"
    #Redundant echo
    echo "$(date -u --date @$((`date +%s` - $date1)) +%H:%M:%S)" >> log.txt
  done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pipe the output to `tee -a` which will send it to standard output and append to log.txt:

```
echo "$(date -u --date @$((`date +%s` - $date1)) +%H:%M:%S)" | tee -a log.txt
```